# FFMPEG errors with non-English characters

Tags: ffmpeg, non-english

When I tried to use the command-line to catch a chrome window with non-English characters such as ¥, or any other 中文页面, an I/O error will occur with the message "Can't find window "¥中文页面。 - Google Chrome", aborting." When the non-English characters are replaced by English ones, the errors will disappear. Environment: Windows 10, ffmpeg version 2021-03-24

This works fine:
`ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="$ English Page - Google Chrome" -pix_fmt yuv420p grab.mp4`

This has errors:
`ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="¥中文页面。 - Google Chrome" -pix_fmt yuv420p grab.mp4`

`"Can't find window "¥中文页面。 - Google Chrome", aborting."`

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Windows 10 default page code for simplified Chinese is 936. You can find your own page code by typing `chcp` in the command line.

FFmpeg fully supports UTF-8, so when I change my Windows default page code to UTF-8 (code 65001), the errors disappeared.

Here is how I did it:

1. <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type `regedit`.
2. Find `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]`
3. Change `OEMCP` value from default (in my case 936) to 65001.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too but duo to old version of ffmpeg which I was used changing Windows default page code to UTF-8 was not work for me. This was a bug in ffmpeg and is fixed from [this commit](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/707f9c9f475f612e196876708cdb5ead31f63525). so updating to newer ffmpeg and `chcp 65001` solved my problem together.